# Fermat's Last Theorem for even indices

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations

My question is related to Fermat’s Last Theorem for even indices. Searching through the internet I came across a book – **13 Lectures on Fermat’s Last Theorem** written by Canadian Professor of Mathematics and Statistics , Paulo Ribenboim. Therein  he shows that the **first** case of FLT has been proven for even indices where

1. **first case** of FLT means $x^n+y^n=z^n$  where $n∤xyz$ and
2. the  **second case** of FLT is where $x^n+y^n=z^n$ and $n|xyz$ and $gcd⁡(x,y,z)=1$

In the book it is mentioned that G. Terjanian had proved the **first** case of FLT.

My question : Prior to Andrew Wiles monumental work did any mathematician prove the **second** case of FLT for even indices ? Any reference to such work would be appreciated

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch - Thanks for the additional tag

Comment: Note that it is sufficient to prove the theorem for $n$ prime because if there where a counter example for some $n$ there would also be one for some prime factor $\ge 2$ of $n$. This doesn't actually proof the theorem for $n$ though.

Comment: @quarague Technically, you have to check $n=4$ as well (which is what Fermat did himself).